# php grid Lite \C_DataGrid' not found

Tags: php, phpgrid

I downloaded PHP grid lite.
using xampp server on my local machine.
It keeps giving me the error Fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'phpGrid_Lite\C_DataGrid' not found

```
require_once("../conf.php");;             
use phpGrid_Lite\C_DataGrid;

$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM Orders", "orderNumber", "Orders");
```

Comment: try `/` maybe help, maybe not. Or You may try `\\\`. It is Windows or Linux/Apple machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to fix.

Your code:

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM Orders", "orderNumber", "Orders");
```

Fix:

```
$dg = new \C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM Orders", "orderNumber", "Orders");
```